# DataTable or Object to json in C# not same System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

There was a problem when I converted DataTable to Json using Newtonsoft.

My server format number is:

```
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ","; // 123,456

System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."; // 0.1123
```

When I used: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table) the output number format different the server number format.
[image]

Comment: ok! good work thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your app should should display number values, not strings.